# Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token in Wordpress button function

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

This is one of my functions I made in wordpress site for button to open shortcode pop up prompt.
Also I saw `<p>` tags are added by wordpress inside function, maybe that could be error in.

```
<input id="textarea" name="textarea" type="text" value="" placeholder="place it here">

<script>
function pol()
{
var x;

var name=prompt("Name","Name");

if (name!=null)
  {
  x = document.getElementById("textarea").value; 
  x = "[pol]" + name + "[/pol]";
  document.getElementById("textarea").value=x;
  }
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="pol" onClick="pol()">
```

Errors:

```
Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token <

Uncaught ReferenceError: pol is not defined
```

In wordpress page, on chrome, inspect element shows function like this:

```
    <input id="textarea" name="textarea" type="text" value="" placeholder="place it here"></p>
    <p><script>
    function pol()
    {
    var x;</p>
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    <p>var name=prompt("Name","Name");</p>
    <p>if (name!=null)
      {
      x = document.getElementById("textarea").value; 
      x = "[pol]" + name + "[/pol]";
      document.getElementById("textarea").value=x;
      }
    }
    </script></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="pol" onClick="pol()"></p>
    Uncaught ReferenceError: pol is not defined (repeated 2 times)
```

I discovered that theme is source of errors.
Somewhere is conflict...

**Solution:**

In every empty line, wordpress theme is coded to ad `<p>` tags, and that made errors, now I fixed function and it is working:

```
<script>
function pol()
{
var x;
var name=prompt("Name","Name");
if (name!=null)
  {
  x = document.getElementById("textarea").value; 
  x = "[pol]" + name + "[/pol]";
  document.getElementById("textarea").value=x;
  }
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="pol" onClick="pol()">
```

Comment: What `<p>` tags? No problems here - http://jsfiddle.net/t9WQB/

Comment: I will update it in question, just a minute.

Comment: Are you pasting this into the WYSIWYG editor or something?

Comment: It is in wordpress page, and wordpress ads wpautop (auto formating) to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add following code in your php page to remove the WordPress pre-coded

tags for every new or empty line. **remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');**